# How to cast my Linq query to the expected Web API return type

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

My .Net Core Web API call is not returning values to the browser, but hanging the browser.

I have these models:

```
public class Status
    {
    public long StatusId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }

public class User
    {
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
    }
```

My Status controller's Get functions look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Status> GetAll()
    {
    var rv =  _context.Statuses.ToList();
    return rv;
    }
```

When I GET the API endpoint, I get the first record, then the browser hangs (keeps loading) and the rest of the data never comes through.

Stepping into my code, I see that rv is getting populated with all of the records, but we have the problem of the `User` having `Statuses` and then the `Statuses` have a `User` and so on - circular reference.

Ok, so let's try this in the controller so we don't get the `Statuses` from `User`:

```
var rv = _context.Statuses.Select(s => new
    {
    StatusId = s.StatusId,
    UserId = s.UserId,
    Body = s.Body,
    User = from u in _context.Users
           select new
               {
               UserId = u.UserId,
               Name = u.Name,
               Email = u.Email,
               }
    }

    ).ToList();

return rv;
```

Problem is `rv` is an anonymous type and I can't figure out how to successfully type it to the `IEnumerable<Status>` return type, even though it is the same as the model (excepting the missing `Statuses` in the `User`). Or do I change the return type and what to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dynamic` as return type or you can create a custom class to save the projection of the query you need:

```
[HttpGet]
public dynamic GetAll()
{
  var rv = _context.Statuses.Select(s => new
  {
   StatusId = s.StatusId,
   UserId = s.UserId,
   Body = s.Body,
   User = from u in _context.Users
          select new
           {
           UserId = u.UserId,
           Name = u.Name,
           Email = u.Email,
           }
   }).ToList();

   return rv;    
}
```

Also you can return a `HttpResponseMessage` :

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
  var rv = _context.Statuses.Select(s => new
  {
   StatusId = s.StatusId,
   UserId = s.UserId,
   Body = s.Body,
   User = from u in _context.Users
          select new
           {
           UserId = u.UserId,
           Name = u.Name,
           Email = u.Email,
           }
   }).ToList();


    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, rv);
}
```

Comment: `Dynamic` was the ticket to ride. Alex's Linq worked better than what I had, even without resorting to ViewModels.

Comment: good to know ;). yes I use dynamic in cases like that, maybe is not the better approach but it works well

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use separate ViewModel/DTO class to send data from API controller. Example:

```
public class StatusModel
    {
    public long StatusId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }

public class UserModel
    {
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    }


public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
  var result = _context.Statuses.Include(e => e.User).Select(e => new StatusModel
    {
    StatusId = e.StatusId,
    UserId = e.UserId,
    Body = e.Body,
    User = new UserModel 
            {
                UserId = e.User.UserId,
                Name = e.User.Name,
                Email = e.User.Email,
            }
    }).ToArray();

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
```

Comment: Since the ViewModels in your example would essentially be identical to my original models, I think that is a complication. However, your Linq is exacly what I have been looking over an hour for, so enthusiastic upvote for that!